# Strawberry-FastAPI: How to call the right function?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, strawberry-graphql

I'm implementing a variation of the file upload in this tutorial:

https://strawberry.rocks/docs/guides/file-upload

The code is basically this:

```
import typing
import strawberry
from strawberry.file_uploads import Upload


@strawberry.input
class FolderInput:
    files: typing.List[Upload]

@strawberry.type
class Mutation:
    @strawberry.mutation
    async def read_file(self, file: Upload) -> str:
        [do some processing]
        return "Processing of PDF done!"
```

I test it with this invocation:

```
curl localhost:8000/graphql \
  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload!){ readFile(file: $file) }", "variables": { "file": null } }' \
  -F map='{ "file": ["variables.file"] }' \
  -F file=@/path/to/some_file.pdf
```

The `CURL` invocation calls `readFile` whereas the mutation in `Strawberry` uses `read_file`, where is that mapping done and can we control that? I'd like multiple read methods (e.g. `read_typeA_pdf`, `read_typeB_pdf`, etc).

Comment: I found the reference of the same in strawberry mutations page and answered accordingly [https://strawberry.rocks/docs/general/mutations](https://strawberry.rocks/docs/general/mutations) - Let me know if needed anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give my share of my knowledge on this is -  the mapping between `the GraphQL mutation name` and `the actual Python method name` is handled by the `Strawberry` library itself

As per your example, I would say  the GraphQL mutation name is `readFile`, while the Python method name is `read_file`. `Strawberry` uses a `snake_case` naming convention to convert the GraphQL operation name to a Python method name

you can try directly as below

```
@strawberry.type
class Mutation:
    @strawberry.mutation
    async def read_typeA_pdf(self, file: Upload) -> str:
        return "Processing of Type A PDF done!"

    @strawberry.mutation
    async def read_typeB_pdf(self, file: Upload) -> str:
        return "Processing of Type B PDF done!"
```

Possibly, With these methods defined, you can now use the following GraphQL mutation names to invoke them like below:

Invoking the `read_typeA_pdf` mutation with a Type A PDF file

```
curl localhost:8000/graphql \
  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload!){ readTypeAPdf(file: $file) }", "variables": { "file": null } }' \
  -F map='{ "file": ["variables.file"] }' \
  -F file=@/path/to/typeA.pdf
```

Invoking the `read_typeB_pdf` mutation with a Type B PDF file:

```
curl localhost:8000/graphql \
  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload!){ readTypeBPdf(file: $file) }", "variables": { "file": null } }' \
  -F map='{ "file": ["variables.file"] }' \
  -F file=@/path/to/typeB.pdf
```

You might  replace `/path/to/typeA.pdf` and `/path/to/typeB.pdf` with the actual paths to your Type A and Type B PDF files, respectively.

https://strawberry.rocks/docs/general/mutations

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @easythrees  - Thanks you! Glad that It solved your issue!